# Running Kafka kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 on Windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to tun the latest version of Kafka (kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0) on windows. I did change the log and tmp directories in all the config files and when I try to start the zookeeper server and getting the below error:

> [2015-12-20 18:43:10,826] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting
>   abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
>   java.io.IOException: Unable to create data directory C:kafka-runtime
>   mp\version-2
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.(FileTxnSnapLog.java:85)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:104)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:86)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:52)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
>           at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)

`C:kafka-runtime` is the directory that I have created `C:\kafka-runtime`, here I can see that "\" is being removed.

Comment: Give a \\ in your configuration for temp directory